# Merge two arrays of pointers into a third array of pointers in C++

Tags: c++, merge

arr1,arr2 are two arrays of pointers, I have to merge these into arr3.
When the program gets arr3[1] (when k=1) the program is closes , I don't get why.

Please help.

```
class Node {
public:
    Node* left;
    T data;
    Node* right;
    int height;
};
    void mergeArrays(Node<T>** arr1,Node<T>** arr2,int len1,int len2){
        int p=0,q=0,k=0;
        Node<T>** arr3 = new Node<T>*[len1+len2];
        
        while ( p < len1 && q < len2) {
                if ((arr1[p])->data< (arr2[q])->data) {
                    (arr3[k++])->data = (arr1[p++])->data;
    
                } else {
                    
                    (arr3[k++])->data = (arr2[q++])->data;    
                }  
            
            }
       
            while ( p < len1) {
                (arr3[k++])->data = (arr1[p++])->data;
            }
            while ( q < len2) {
         
                (arr3[k++])->data = (arr2[q++])->data; 
            }
    
            
            
    }
```

Comment: You're not copying pointers; you are copying data from dereferenced members to other dereferenced members of objects that don't exist. And I have no idea what you hoped to accomplish with `cout << arr3[c] << " ";`, since all that does is drop a pointer into `cout` unless you have some secret operator overload buried the the code you're not showing us (but should be, as part of a proper [mcve]).

Comment: Just to add to @WhozCraig's comment, if you intend to implement a shallow-copy, please copy the pointers instead of copying the `data` data-member. Otherwise, if you intend to implement a deep-copy, then do a separate heap-allocation for each element of `arr3` using `new` using a suitable constructor that takes `data` as an argument.

Comment: What about using `std::merge`? It is quite flexible, less bug-prone, easier to maintain and possibly faster (not to mention there is now a parallel implementation available).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not copying pointers. You're copying values from one `data` member of some object to another `data` member of some object. But the problem is, there is no "there" there to copy *to* . You allocate a bed of pointers for `arr3`, but there are no objects behind those pointers so this:

```
(arr3[k++])->data = (arr1[p++])->data;
```

Invokes undefined behavior.

I'm fairly certain this is what you were shooting for:

```
template<class T>
Node<T>** mergeArrays(Node<T> **arr1, Node<T> **arr2, int len1, int len2)
{
    int p = 0, q = 0, k = 0;
    Node<T> **arr3 = new Node<T> *[len1 + len2];

    while (p < len1 && q < len2)
    {
        if ((arr1[p])->data < (arr2[q])->data)
        {
            arr3[k++] = arr1[p++];
        }
        else
        {
            arr3[k++] = arr2[q++];
        }
    }

    while (p < len1)
    {
        arr3[k++] = arr1[p++];
    }
    while (q < len2)
    {
        arr3[k++] = arr2[q++];
    }

    return arr3;
}
```